# Cypher order by aggregation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I need to aggregate data during the query and then order by this data.

According to cypher documentation:

> If you want to use aggregations to sort your result set, the
>   aggregation must be included in the RETURN to be used in your ORDER
>   BY.

I have the following cypher query:

```
START profile=node(31) MATCH (profile)-[r:ROLE]->(story)
WHERE r.role="LEADER" and story.status="PRIVATE" 
WITH story MATCH (story)<-[r?:RATED]-() 
RETURN distinct story ,sum(r.rate) as rate ORDER BY rate DESCENDING
```

The above query works fine, the thing is I must include ***sum(r.rate)*** in my result set.

I am using **Cypherdsl** via repository ( my repository extends CypherDslRepository ) when quering the response should be story list/page...

Can I use order by aggregation function without including it in the result set?
Any workaround for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with an intermediate `WITH``

```
START profile=node(31) MATCH (profile)-[r:ROLE]->(story)
WHERE r.role="LEADER" and story.status="PRIVATE" 
WITH story 
MATCH (story)<-[r?:RATED]-() 
WITH story ,sum(r.rate) as rate 
ORDER BY rate DESCENDING
RETURN story
```

And leave off `DISTINCT` if you already have aggregation.

And optional relationships are slow, so if you run into an perf issue rather use a path expression and get the rel from there.

```
START profile=node(31) MATCH (profile)-[r:ROLE]->(story)
WHERE r.role="LEADER" and story.status="PRIVATE" 
with story, extract(p in (story)<-[r?:RATED]-() : head(rels(p)) as rated
WITH story , reduce(sum = 0, r in rated : sum + r.rate)  as rate 
ORDER BY rate DESCENDING
RETURN story
```

Comment: hi Michael thank you for the response...cypherdsl not allow order by after with (WithNext class ain't got the method orderBy ).. any suggestions?